# Enviar imagem para Servidor

Tags: java, android

Quando envio um byte[] convertido em String para o servidor no servidor vem vazio ou rebenta. Não percebo o porquê.

```
  Bitmap photo = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
                    photo = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, 800, 1422, false);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);

                    byte[] imageArray = bytes.toByteArray();

                    String imageAsString = Base64.encodeToString(imageArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Depois para enviar para o servidor faço:

```
private String InsertImage(String url)
{
    HttpClient client = buildHttpClient();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
    HttpResponse response = null;
    String responseString = "";

    try
    {
        System.out.println("VOU PARA O SERVIDOR");
        JSONObject jsonObject = this.setHeadersAndbuildJSONObject(request);

        System.out.println("vou levar 1 - " + sessionID);
        System.out.println("vou levar 2 - " + data[0]);
        System.out.println("vou levar 3 - " + data[1]);

        jsonObject.put("SessionGUID", sessionID);
        jsonObject.put("Address", data[0]);
        jsonObject.put("imageAsBytes", data[1]);

        responseString = this.executeRequest(jsonObject, request, response, client);
        System.out.println("VIM DO SERVIDOR " + responseString.toString());

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("ERRO " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return responseString;
}
```

No system.out que vêem as variáveis vão todas bem preenchidas.
No lado do servidor rebentae vem com o seguinte erro "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Answer (score 1):

Olá! Você está mandando a imagem em byte[] para o server por algum motivo especial ?

Porque você não utiliza uma lib de http para enviar o arquivo por HTTP POST ? Vai ser muito mais simples, e não precisa inventar a roda, serializar e deserializar, etc.

No link abaixo tem um exemplo pronto exatamente do que você precisa:

http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83

Comment: o envio para o Servidor nesta app foi feito assim pelo que não vou poder remodelar toda a app nesse sentido que você apontou. No entanto ela não é enviada em byte[] mas sim em String que vai dentro de um Object[].

Comment: Entendi. O que você deve ver é como que estes dados devem ser encodados. Em geral, base64 é utilizado, mas o desenvolvedor da parte do app pode ter utilizado outra coisa. Aparentemente o desenvolvedor está esperando um objeto serializado, e não um byteArray encodado em base64. A minha sugestão é você ver mais detalhes de como o servidor espera que você mande o objeto, pois caso contrário, será um tiro no escuro ... tentativa e erro ...

Comment: Obrigado, do lado do servidor ele está á espera de uma String e depois lá trata da String de modo a colocar a foto no AzureStorage por isso é que no código depois de tirar a fotografia eu fiz o seguinte "                    String imageAsString = Base64.encodeToString(imageArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
" e enviei para o servidor a variável "imageAsString" mas no caso parece que rebenta

Comment: Justamente, dá erro porque parece que não é o base64 que ele está esperando que você mande ...

Comment: eu estou a enviar em String embora na base64, e do lado do servidor está á espera de uma String penso que a base64 não faz ter este erro.